# Remove Personal Options section only from subscribers profile

Tags: profiles

I've seen there are already similar questions but my specific purpose is deleting/hiding personal options from ONLY subscribers' profiles, so the action is defined towards a SPECIFIC ROLE

This is a generic function I found here, I suppose it works for ALL THE ROLES

```
// removes the `profile.php` admin color scheme options
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'cor_remove_personal_options' ) ) {
  /**
   * Removes the leftover 'Visual Editor', 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and 'Toolbar' options.
   */
  function cor_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
    $subject = preg_replace( '#<h3>Personal Options</h3>.+?/table>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
    return $subject;
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_start() {
    ob_start( 'cor_remove_personal_options' );
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```